# Boundedness of the solutions of the equation $y'' + x y = 0 $ as $x \rightarrow +\infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the Airy equation. We know that the two solutions are both bounded as $x\rightarrow \infty$.

The picture is that the solution just oscillates with higher and higher frequency ($\propto \sqrt{x}$) but its amplitude does not increase.

Can we develop this into a general theorem?

Are the solutions of the equation $y''+ x^2 y = 0 $ bounded in both directions?

Comment: Look up perturbation theory.